# Dotnet core 3.1: Making one common method to call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a question about how i can make a common method of the following method's and how can i call the common method. I want to make a generic method which i can use.

```
    private async Task<bool> GetObjA()
    {
        var ObjA = await _unitOfWork.RepositoryA.CheckExists(TableField, TableFieldValue);
        if (ObjA != null)
        {
            ValidatedObjects.Add(TableName.ToLower(), ObjA);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

   private async Task<bool> GetObjB()
    {
        var ObjB = await _unitOfWork.RepositoryB.CheckExists(TableField, TableFieldValue);
        if (ObjB != null)
        {
            ValidatedObjects.Add(TableName.ToLower(), ObjB);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

   private async Task<bool> GetObjC()
    {
        var ObjC = await _unitOfWork.RepositoryC.CheckExists(TableField, TableFieldValue);
        if (ObjC != null)
        {
            ValidatedObjects.Add(TableName.ToLower(), ObjC);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this by making a single generic method that receives the object as a parameter.

This snippet should do the job:

```cs
private async Task<bool> GetObj<T>(T myObject)
{
      if (myObject != null)
      {
            ValidatedObjects.Add(TableName.ToLower(), myObject);
            return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

Explanation:

Rather than getting the object inside the method, you will pass it as a generic data type to the method. This means you will use **unitOfWork** outside the method so you can be generic and avoid repeating yourself each time.

References:

[Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)

Comment: Thank you Mohammed. I'll Try it can you give a example of how to call it

Comment: you will have something like
var ObjA = await _unitOfWork.RepositoryA.CheckExists(TableField, TableFieldValue);
GetObj(ObjA);

Comment: But then l will have multiple statements like var Objb= waait

Comment: If you want to process all 3 objects in 1 call then you either modify the code to process the objects once

Comment: Or you can do something that includes lists and loops. But this will still call the method more than once

Comment: Does this mean that i have multiple statements. One for ObjA en ObjB en ObjC?

Comment: I mean you will populate objA, objB, objC. Then you will process all these objects inside the method.

Comment: If this helped you. Please mark out the answer so people could benefit too